# What's the difference between fetch and fetch next?

Tags: sql-server

I've got a cursor sending out pager messages, and occasionally it sends out duplicates. The syntax looks like this:

```
    declare @col1 varchar(255),
    @col2 varchar(255)

    declare c cursor local for

    select column1, column2
    from table
    where flippity = 'floppity'

    open c
    fetch  from c into @col1, @col2
    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin

    sp_do_your_thing @col1, @col2

    fetch next from c into @col1, @col2
    end
    close c
    deallocate c
```

**Question:** if I'm getting duplicates, could it be the fetches? do they both need to be fetch next, or neither?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no difference, and omitting `NEXT` will not lead to duplicates or different results in any way. `NEXT` is just an explicit declaration of the default behavior. From [the syntax diagram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/fetch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
FETCH   
      [ [ NEXT | PRIOR | FIRST | LAST   
                | ABSOLUTE { n | @nvar }   
                | RELATIVE { n | @nvar }   
           ]   
           FROM
```

`NEXT` is not the only option, and most of the other options are only available with certain types of cursors. It's hard for me to get into this habit, because I exclusively use fast-forward, single-pass, "firehose" cursors, but best practice is to include `NEXT` explicitly.

I would look at the query, as I suspect it will also be returning duplicates when there is no cursor involved. Or, whatever the stored procedure is doing, is making it *seem* like there are duplicates. Another possible explanation is if the query is using `WITH (NOLOCK)` / `READUNCOMMITTED` and you are reading the same row twice in an allocation order scan due to data movement.